# Continuous Image Marquee

Tags: java, android, image

I'm just curious if anyone knows the easiest solution for an image marquee in Android with clickable events, etc.

I've looked at a few various projects and flicked through the manual, but I can't seem to find anything appropriate.

I would like to create a scrolling image effect similar to the Expedia android application homepage. See https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.expedia.bookings&hl=en

What I've looked at so far :

**FragmentActivity** -- Scrolling seems jittery and would take a fair old amount of adapting to achieve what I want

**HorizontalScrollView** -- Limited scroll functionality (this would be perfect if I could 
continiously loop the contents, but short of overriding the draw I can't see how it's possible)

**GLSurfaceView** -- So far this seems like it's the only viable solution, but it's gonna take me a while to implement all the functionality manually

Before I get cracking deep into the OpenGL route it would be of great help to know if there is something out there that can already do this.

If anyone could suggest anything it would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: check this https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-DirectionalViewPager
or this
https://github.com/LambergaR/VerticalViewPager/
both are using Viewpager but extend it to work "Vertically"

Comment: Thanks, but neither seem to be a viable solution. I'm gonna have a play around with the HorizontalScrollView first and if no luck then do a complete GLSurfaceView. If I can remember I will try to post my final solution here when I'm done.

Comment: I found basically a bit of a hack:

Take the following code : https://github.com/MeetMe/Android-HorizontalListView 

Change the constructor values to :

`code`

    
    private synchronized void initView() {
        mLeftViewIndex = Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2;
        mRightViewIndex = Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2 + 1;
        mDisplayOffset = 0;
        mNextX = Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2;
        mCurrentX = Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2;
        mMaxX = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        mScroller = new Scroller( getContext() );
        mGesture = new GestureDetector(getContext(), mOnGesture);
    }
`code`

Comment: Then in the adapter do the following :

`code`
  @Override
  public int getCount()
  {
   return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
  }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int position)
  {
   return objects[ position % objects.length ];
  }
`code`

This hack will work for something like scrolling a billion items either direction.

Sorry, I couldn't post this as an answer stack overflow has banned my from answering questions (something to do with poor answers or something).

Hope this helps others with the same issue.